# What is nucleus of head syntactic function?

Tags: grammar

> He is an honest person.

Here is there any nucleus of syntactic function?

I found it in Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_relation

Comment: Sorry, what definition of "nucleus" are you using?

Comment: @alphabet Of head syntactic function. I found it in Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_relation

Comment: There is no mention of "nucleus" in that article.

Comment: @Salimuddin Of what possible interest is it to you?

Comment: @Joachim Go to that page. And then look at the picture of syntactic function below.

Comment: @Salimuddin Your question is closed for the reason given, and therefore you should not expect answers.

Comment: You asked a similar question on ELL, where you were told to go to SE Linguistics, which you said you would do. I suggest that the study of nuclei is too advanced for your present level of knowledge.

Comment: @BillJ sorry for that. But it is making me confused. Wikipedia says **head** is also called **nucleus**. But in syntactic function, they divided **Nucleus** as a sub-class of h**ead**. But why?